# What is the difference between scopes and self methods in my example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I faced a case when I need to use find_by_sql. (No other varients were found. It's a topic for another question, but I don't have enough time to explain it).

So i have two tables T1, T2 and a model... lets call it 'Item'

So now I will write an example when scope and self method works pretty differently and I don't understand why. It's not a real code, but just a small example.

```
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :my_selection_scope, lambda { |var| find_by_sql(["SELECT T1.*, 
    T2.name AS t2_name
    FROM T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id
    WHERE T1.value = ?", var])
  }

  def self.my_selection_method(var)
    find_by_sql(["SELECT T1.*, T2.name AS t2_name
      FROM T1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T2.t1_id = T1.id
      WHERE T1.value = ?", var])
  end
end
```

From console:

```
Item.my_selection_scope(var)[0].t2_name
=> undefined method 't2_name' for #<Item>
Item.my_selection_method(var)[0].t2_name
=> "success"
```

I don't understand why scope didn't give me the 't2_name' value, when self method did it without any problems. Can somebody tell me why is it hapenning?

Comment: Try `Item.my_selection_scope(var)[0][:t2_name]`

Comment: [:t2_name] worked ok, but why I can't reach it with .t2_name?

Comment: Looks like I was wrong... [:t2_name] always returns nil